# Pandas - Numbers turn to months

Tags: python, pandas

When i convert my pandas dataframe to csv, some numbers turn to months.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwZO1.png)

It only happens when it converts to csv.

This is my code:

```
 import requests
my_url = requests.get('http://www.vivoelfutbol.com.mx/futbolmexicano.php') 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
page_soup = soup(my_url.text, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"bordermitad"})[0].findAll("div", {"class":"det"})
#dates = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"bordermitad"})[0].findAll("div", {"class":"tif"})

#for result in dates:
    #date = result.text.strip()
    #print(date + "\n")

calendario = []
for result2 in containers:
    time = result2.find('div', {'class':'hor'}).text
    hometeam = result2.find('a').text
    score = result2.find('a', {'title':'Analisis y Antecedentes'}).text
    awayteam = result2.find('div', {'class':'eqvc'}).text
    calendario.append((time, hometeam, score, awayteam))
    #print("\n" + time + " " + hometeam + " " + score + " " + awayteam + "\n")

import os
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(calendario, columns=['Hora', 'Equipo_1', 'Marcador', 'Equipo 2']) 
if not os.path.isfile('Marcadores_futbol_mexico.csv'):
    df.to_csv('Marcadores_futbol_mexico.csv', index=True)
else:
    df.to_csv('Marcadores_futbol_mexico.csv', mode ='a')
```

EDIT: Printing df i get this:

```
    Hora   Equipo_1 Marcador   Equipo 2
0  19:30       UNAM      1-4    America
1  21:30    Tijuana      1-1  Monterrey
2  19:30     Tigres      2-0     Santos
3  21:30    Morelia      2-2     Toluca
4  19:00    America      ---       UNAM
5  21:00  Monterrey      ---    Tijuana
6  12:00     Toluca      ---    Morelia
7  18:00     Santos      ---     Tigres
```

In the csv, it shows this:

```
Hora    Equipo_1    Marcador    Equipo 2
0   19:30   UNAM    4-Jan   America
1   21:30   Tijuana 1-Jan   Monterrey
2   19:30   Tigres  Feb-00  Santos
3   21:30   Morelia 2-Feb   Toluca
4   19:00   America --- UNAM
5   21:00   Monterrey   --- Tijuana
6   12:00   Toluca  --- Morelia
7   18:00   Santos  --- Tigres
```

EDIT 2: Solved, it was excel messing with me :P

Comment: I can't replicate the issue you have. If I have "4-Jan" in a csv file, it gets read into `pandas` as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you opening the CSV to see the data in it? If you're opening in Excel it might be converting the actual CSV data of (1-4) to (4-Jan). Have you tried opening in a text editor?

Comment: Oh... Excel pls.
Is there a way to make excel show the data correctly?

Comment: @Dominic You'd probably have to find a setting in Excel that says "autodetect format" or something similar and disable it.